# User-defined table functions in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400, zos, db2-luw, table-functions

I would like to know the DB2 platforms where it is possible to create User-defined table functions in SQL-PL. It seems that it is possible in DB2 for i, but I haven't seen anything for LUW, not z/OS.

It does not appear in the "SQL Reference for Cross-Platform Development Version" as many other popular features.

Comment: Both DB2 for LUW and z/OS support SQL table functions -- check out the SQL reference. `CREATE FUNCTION blah ... RETURNS TABLE ...`

Comment: Thank you. That's true. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-power-of-udtf/ This article is for DB2 for i, however many things works for other platforms.